# Is it known if there are non-Interdictor tactics to stop ships in hyperspace?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, hyperspace

As pirates can't always wait in specific systems I'm wondering if there is a tactic (or more than one) to get ships to drop out of hyperspace where the pirates want them (even if the pirates are lacking any Interdictor cruiser)?

Legends and canon answers are both searched for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Canon

**To the best of my knowledge, none is mentioned.** Pirate tactics most likely consist of waiting around locations where ships are likely to enter or leave hyperspace. This was the strategy employed by some pilots of Wilhuff Tarkin’s acquantaince, for example, though this relied on their prey having poor computing technology:

> Lommite convoys typically comprised up to a score of unpiloted
> container ships slave-rigged to a crewed shepherd vessel, now and then
> with an armed gunboat trailing. Each container was capable of jumping
> to hyperspace, but during those years before the era of affordable and
> reliable navicomputers, the convoys had to navigate by hyperspace
> buoys located along the route, and experience had proved that jumping
> in single file was safer than going to hyperspace in clusters, **even
> though the maneuver left the containers vulnerable to attack on their
> reversions to realspace.**
>
> <sub>*Tarkin*</sub>

Nonetheless, pirates were employing a similar strategy many years later, when Luke Skywalker encountered some. In this case, they were lurking in the Nanthri system, a popular jumping-off point—a hyperspace roundabout, if you will. Presumably such necessities were diminished but not eliminated by improvements in navicomputer technology.

> “That small fleet was patrolling the sector of space that would come
> from Exodeen.”
>
> “So? That’s what pirates do.”
>
> <sub>*Heir to the Jedi*</sub>

Another possibility would be waiting in popular *destinations*. A pirate could catch a ship right as it was leaving (while it took its time getting out of the planet’s gravity well), or as it was arriving (since it has to leave hyperpace to land on a planet).

### Legends

**There are some.** A whole array of non-Interdictor technologies for creating gravity wells are mentioned in Legends, but most of them don’t seem like the sort of thing pirates would be able to afford. There are relatively cheap methods of dragging ships out of hyperspace, however.
Pirates would sometimes drag massive bodies into well-traveled hyperspace routes, forcing any ship employing these routes to drop out of space.

> The Argaian pirates led by Xer, father of Xim the Despot, intercepted
> ships by towing asteroids into the narrow hyperspace lanes through the
> Indrexu Spiral, and similar tactics are still used today. Another
> strategy is to scatter small bits of ice, dust, or metal chaff
> (popularly known as decant dust) across a hyperspace lane.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: The Essential Guide to Warfare*</sub>

Presumably it would take a *lot* of dust to be massive enough.

All the methods mentioned in canon could also be employed.